# Looping routine to evaluate a recursively defined function

Tags: recursion, procedural-programming

I'd like to do a calculation which is basically a looping routine to evaluate a recursively defined function. For example:

```
f1[x_, y_, f4_] := x + y + f4

f2[x_, y_, w_, f4_] := x + y + w + f4

f3[x_, y_, f4_] := 2 x + 2 y + f4

f4[w_, f1_, f2_, f3_] := w + f1 + f2 + f3
```

And I know that `x = 1, y = 1, w = 1` and the initial value of `f4 = 1`; thus, I'd like to repeat the `f4` calculation until it reaches a constant value.

What a really want is like:

First loop:

```
f1 = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3
f2 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 4
f3 = 2 + 2 + 1 = 5
f4 = 1 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 13
```

Second loop: F4 = 13

```
f1 = 1 + 1 + 13 = 15
f2 = 1 + 1 +1 + 13 = 16
f3 = 2 + 2 + 13 = 17
f4 = 1 + 15 + 16 + 17 = 49
```

and so on.

Comment: `f4` will explode, don't you think?

Comment: Yes, but it's the calculus routine that will help me. This basic example will help in a more complex one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define `step` as the function that describes how `f4` evolves at each step given the values of arguments `x`, `y`, `w` and `z`:

```
ClearAll[step]
step[x_, y_, w_, z_] := w + f1[x, y, z] + f2[x, y, w, z] + f3[x, y, z]
```

Taking 3 `step`s with symbolic arguments:

```
NestList[step[x, y, w, #]&, α, 3]
```

> {α, 2 w + 4 x + 4 y + 3 α, 
>    8 w + 16 x + 16 y + 9 α, 26 w + 52 x + 52 y + 27 α}

Taking 10 `step`s with an initial value `1` for `z`:

```
NestList[step[1, 1, 1, #]&, 1, 10]
```

> {1, 13, 49, 157, 481, 1453, 4369, 13117, 39361, 118093, 354289}